# Meteor SEO render and subscriptions

Tags: node.js, meteor, seo, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I'm working on SEO of a web application using meteor.

On this website during the subscription to data we use a template to show a loading circle.

When I use the Googlebot view  to look how google indexes my page, I am only able to see the layout and this loading circle.

I notice, when this circle appear, the browser icon is like loaded.

It's like if the Googlebot doesn't wait for the subscriptions in the template.

I have no problem with subscription in iron-router.

Anyone has informations about it ?

Ps : We already use the spiderable package and I think it's a problem with reactiv var to notice the subscriptions are ready.

Comment: The `spiderable` package uses `phantomjs` to render pages for crawlers by looking for the `_escaped_fragment_` query string parameter. Spiderable will wait for subscriptions to finish loading before rendering the page.

Comment: Thank you for replying, and sorry about forget  notice we are already using spiderable to get this result.